# mongo deleteOne not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple action I'm trying to take to delete a single record in my db. I'm following the instructions to the letter:

```
db.users.deleteOne({login:"theUsersName"})
```

But for some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Property 'deleteOne' of object synctup.users is not a function
```

What am I missing here????

Comment: Running in what exactly? Looks like nodejs by the error. Where is `db` coming from in your code?

Comment: No. This is directly in the command line using mongo client

Comment: Would have been a clearer question if you included the `E QUERY` part or then basically the whole error line since it's then obvious it's the shell. You are using a MongoDB version prior to 3.2 so it does not have a `deleteOne()` method. The method only aliases `remove()` anyway, and is simply "preferred" in modern API's due to it being more descriptive as to what it does and effectively adds the `justOne` option to the call. `db.users.remove({ "login": "theUsersName" },{ justOne: true })` is essentially the same thing. Best really to "uprade" your MongoDB, since 3.2 is the min supported.